# Laravel Eloquent, adding relation with limited rows turns up empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using Spatie Querybuilder (v1.11) to return filtered and paginated results. This in turn is using Laravel Eloquent. The query returns a number of albums with related media items, and I wanted to limit the number of media items for each album. Instead the "media" property returns empty.

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        
        $query = QueryBuilder::for(Album::class)
                ->with(['media' => function($query) {
                    $query->limit(4);
                }])
                ->get(); 
        return $query;
```

Logging the query looks fine:

```
 "query": "select * from `media` where `media`.`model_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
           6, 7, 8, 9)           //<-- and so on, continues to 227 
  limit 4"
```

But the result is with an empty "media":

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 227,
            "name": "Good",
            "media": []
```

If I don't use the "limit" specification and only use ->with('media'), I get all the images, but I only want 4 of each media.

**Update**

The problem is not related to Spatie Querybuilder. I was wrong about the media being empty, actually the first row had 4 media items, but since the result shows in descending order I thought all of the albums had empty items.
So the problem is that the query limits the number of items to 4 for the complete result, not for each album.
I found a solution for it though(see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I needed to get 4 items per album, I first did a query getting the albums:

```
$query = QueryBuilder::for(Album::class)
                ->allowedSorts('created_at')
                ->has('media');                      //<-- only albums that has media 

$result = $query->paginate()->toArray();
```

Then I looped the result and got the associated items (4 of each) and attached it as a property to the result:

```
//Loop the albums and for each album add 4 of its related media

        foreach($result['data'] as &$album) {

            $mediaItems = Media::where('model_id', $album['id'])
                    ->limit(4)
                    ->get();
            $album['media'] = $mediaItems;           // <------

        }
        return $result;
```